# To use several parameters that are in a .lst

Tags: bash, sql

I've a doc.lst that is :

```
   23/02/2015  0  AAA
   23/02/2015  0  AB1
   23/02/2015  0  AC2
   23/02/2015  0  FRR
   23/02/2015  0  FPT
   23/02/2015  0  PEI
   23/02/2015  0  PEA
```

I would like to know how to do in my sqlplus request how to select each part as a parameter.

This is my SQL request :

```
   UPDATE P
   SET P.DATED='&1', P.DATEF='&1', P.COD='&2', P.CODB='&3'
   WHERE P.G_BAT=1;
   COMMIT;
```

My sql query is for something that is like

```
   sqlplus user/pass@ORACLE_SID update_p.sql 23/02/2015 0 AAA
```

But I would like to use

```
    while read line
    do
    sqlplus user/pass@ORACLE_SID update_p.sql doc.lst
    commit;
    done;
```

The thing that I want is to update my table P with the datas included in my doc.lst. I want the first element of my first line, the second and the third to update my table P. At the end of this shell i've a command that generate a flow xml.

Comment: There is *nothing* in `doc.lst` that appears to be even remotely related to your SQL request...

Comment: Yes my sql querry is for something that is like sqlplus user/pass@ORACLE_SID update_p 23/02/2015 0 AAA but i would like to use update_p doc.lst

Comment: Edit that information into your post...

Comment: `while read -r line; do sqlplus user/pass@ORACLE_SID "$line"; done < doc.lst` See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Where do I put my update_p.sql into this line? Before "$line"?

Comment: @JulienS Where is the `.txt` mentioned in your title? What role does it play?

Comment: My .txt is doc.lst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(cat doc.lst)
do
    P1=$(echo $i|awk '{print $1}')
    P2=$(echo $i|awk '{print $2}')
    P3=$(echo $i|awk '{print $3}')
    #now your SQL set would look like **SET P.DATED='$P1', P.DATEF='$P1', P.COD='$P2', P.CODB='$P3'** and you can launch your sql
done
```

Comment: After your command I use update_p.sql P1 P2 P3 and it says that the command is not found at the beggining of P1=23/02/2... and the same thing for P2=0 and P3=AAA.

Comment: What I posted is not a command, it's a script. You can use it to generate a updata_p.sql. Run the script to generate the file with as many sql instructions as lines in doc.lst and after that run the sqlplus line.

Comment: Could you edit your post and explain it please? I don't really understand what you mean. I've to create an update.sh that countains what you wrote. And in my own shell use the sqlplus command?

Comment: Well, if I edit you will be updating record where P.G_BAT=1 again and again until it has the last update from doc.lst. Which I think is not what you really want, otherwise you can just `tail doc.lst` and use those values. Obviously you are going to modify P.G_BAT for every new value you get from doc.lst so that different records are updated, and that is an information you didn't post.

Comment: Every line of my doc.lst is something that i want to upload. I don't understand your last message, I just want to take the first word of each line as parameter 1, the second as parameter 2 and the third as parameter 3.

Comment: is this (SET P.DATED='&1', P.DATEF='&1', P.COD='&2', P.CODB='&3'
  WHERE P.G_BAT=1;) what you want? If it is, then you are doing nothing but updating your database records where P.G_BAT=1 to the last entry in your doc.lst, since every update will be overwriten with the next update.

Comment: The thing that I want is to update my table P with the datas included in my doc.lst. I want the first element of my first line, the second and the third to update my table P. At the end of this shell i've a command that generate a flow xml.